# Understanding how to send encrypted AES key along with encrypted email message for S/MIME

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, aes, rsa, smime

Hi I need to make a mailing system wherein I need to do the following:

- Generate an AES 256 key
- Encrypt Email using this aes-256 key
- Encrypt the aes-256 key using the recipients public key
- Sign the email using my private key
- Send all of these to the recipient

I have been following [this](https://tools.ietf.org/doc/python-m2crypto/howto.smime.html) to do the encryption with aes-256 and sign with my private key. I however do not know how I can encrypt the aes-256 key using the RSA public key and send it in the same email. I'm looking at a python approach but if someone can point me to even an openssl command line version of this I can write a python wrapper to achieve the same.

EDIT:

I currently use this method to encrypt via S/MIME using AES 256:

```
def sendsmime(from_addr, to_addrs, subject, msg, from_key, from_cert=None, to_certs=None):
msg_bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(msg)
sign = from_key
encrypt = to_certs

s = SMIME.SMIME()
if sign:
    s.load_key(from_key, from_cert)
    p7 = s.sign(msg_bio, flags=SMIME.PKCS7_TEXT)
    msg_bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(msg) # Recreate coz sign() has consumed it.

if encrypt:
    sk = X509.X509_Stack()
    for x in to_certs:
        sk.push(X509.load_cert(x))
    s.set_x509_stack(sk)
    s.set_cipher(SMIME.Cipher('aes_256_cbc'))
    tmp_bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
    if sign:
        s.write(tmp_bio, p7)
    else:
        tmp_bio.write(msg)
    p7 = s.encrypt(tmp_bio)

out = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
out.write('From: %s\r\n' % from_addr)
out.write('To: %s\r\n' % to_addrs)
out.write('Subject: %s\r\n' % subject) 
if encrypt:
    s.write(out, p7)
else:
    if sign:
        s.write(out, p7, msg_bio, SMIME.PKCS7_TEXT)
    else:
        out.write('\r\n')
        out.write(msg)
out.close()

smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
smtp.connect('smtp.provider.net', 587)
smtp.login('username', 'password')
smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, out.read())
smtp.quit()
```

Comment: Show what you've tried.  Your question is too broad currently.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark updated with the method I am using, is there something else I can add?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using M2Crypto which already includes support for S/MIME. It takes care of all the details for you! It will perform the encryption and signing. You do not have to explicitly encrypt the secret and attach it to the message. M2Crypto does this for you.